# How to display form in table under custom tabs with add more options button in magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.6

I need this anyone can help me
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create this using this below code

1. **etc/adminhtml/system.xml**

   ```
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
   <system>
       <section id="general" type="text">
           <group id="quantity_ranges" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
               <label>Quantity Ranges</label>
               <field id="ranges" translate="label" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                   <label>Ranges</label>
                   <frontend_model>Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\Ranges</frontend_model>
                   <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>
               </field>
           </group>
       </section>
   </system>
   </config>
   ```
2. **app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Form/Field/Ranges.php**

   ```
   <?php
   namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field;

    use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray;
    use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

    class Ranges extends AbstractFieldArray
    {

       /**
       * Prepare rendering the new field by adding all the needed 
      columns
       */
       protected function _prepareToRender()
       {
           $this->addColumn('from_qty', ['label' => __('From'), 'class' => 'required-entry']);
           $this->addColumn('to_qty', ['label' => __('To'), 'class' => 'required-entry']);
           $this->addColumn('price', ['label' => __('Price'), 'class' => 'required-entry']);
           $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add');
       } 
    }
   ```
3. **Run Commands**

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:s:d:-f

php bin/magento c:c

php bin/magento c:f

Comment: Thanks for your response, not looking for add in configuration, i created new module and add menu and when click on menu open page and in this page having multiple tabs and there is one option tab and now when i click on option tab then this form should be open
 $this->addTab(
            'options',
            [
                'label' => __('Options'),
                'title' => __('Options'),
                'content' => $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                    'Custom\ExtraFees\Block\Adminhtml\ExtraFees\Tab\Options'
                )->toHtml()
            ]
        );